# Change the database name on the fly in CodeIgniter 3

Tags: database, codeigniter, configuration

I have need to change the database name after a user is verified. In the database.php file there is this.

```
 $db['default'] = array(....
     'database' => 'databasename1',
...
  );
```

I know that you can display the value of database with $this->db->database.  I would like to change it to another name for the duration of the users session.

I have tried using $this->db->set_database('databasename2') and various other attempts with no solution.  I have also searched and can not find the solution.

Anyone know how to change the database name for the duration of the users session?

Comment: why do you need to do that ?

Comment: Each company has it's own database and the user log in provides the database name.

Comment: then i guess it's better to put the database name in the session and then call it or rename it from the session , it makes more sense

Comment: or you can use multiple databases like in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15348423/codeigniter-multiple-databases-accessing-database-config-in-a-second-database

Comment: That is what I am trying to figure out how to do, is get the database name out of the session into the database name in the database.php file when it is read.  there is an error that happens when trying to access the $this that states you can not do that when 'not in object context'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

so you can get the connection details from the session and connect to the database manually using those details and close it when done

**Manually Connecting to a Database**

```
$this->load->database();
```

The first parameter of this function can optionally be used to specify a particular database group from your config file, or you can even submit connection values for a database that is not specified in your config file. Examples:

To choose a specific group from your config file you can do this:

```
$this->load->database('group_name');
```

Where group_name is the name of the connection group from your config file.

To connect manually to a desired database you can pass an array of values:

```
$config['hostname'] = "localhost";
$config['username'] = "myusername";
$config['password'] = "mypassword";
$config['database'] = "mydatabase";
$config['dbdriver'] = "mysql";
$config['dbprefix'] = "";
$config['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$config['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$config['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$config['cachedir'] = "";
$config['char_set'] = "utf8";
$config['dbcollat'] = "utf8_general_ci";

$this->load->database($config);
```

For information on each of these values please see the configuration page.

Or you can submit your database values as a Data Source Name. DSNs must have this prototype:

```
$dsn = 'dbdriver://username:password@hostname/database';

$this->load->database($dsn);
```

To override default config values when connecting with a DSN string, add the config variables as a query string.

```
$dsn = 'dbdriver://username:password@hostname/database?char_set=utf8&dbcollat=utf8_general_ci&cache_on=true&cachedir=/path/to/cache';

$this->load->database($dsn);
```

**Manually closing the Connection**

While CodeIgniter intelligently takes care of closing your database connections, you can explicitly close the connection.

```
$this->db->close();
```

for more about connecting to multiple databases read this https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/connecting.html

Comment: Not working
Message: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead

Filename: mysql/mysql_driver.php

Line Number: 136

Backtrace:

File: /var/www/REPO/cgen/application/controllers/Cgen.php
Line: 28
Function: database

File: /var/www/REPO/cgen/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue this way which seems clean to me unless someone sees a security issue.

set session in auto load.

In database.php

```
 $ci = get_instance();
 if (!isset($ci->session->userdata['clientdb'])){
      $ci->session->set_userdata('clientdb','database1');
 }

 $active_group = 'default';
 $query_builder = TRUE;

 $db['default'] = array(
      ........
      'database' => $ci->session->userdata['clientdb'],
      ..........
 );
```

The database value is set via the cleintdb value of the users session.

Comment: this won't work, since the library is not initialized yet

Answer (score 0):

here is your solution. build all links with corresponding client ID and change database.php like

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['clid'])) {
    $efg = (int) $_REQUEST['clid'];
} else {
  die('wrong URL');
}

$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=client_db,client_dbuser,clientdb_pass');

 $sql = 'SELECT db_username,db_name,db_pass FROM clients WHERE id=?';

$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
 $sth->execute(array($efg));
$d_result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if (count($d_result) < 1) {
  die('Wrong client');
}


$active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;

$db['default'] = array(
'dsn' => '',
'hostname' => 'localhost',
'username' => $d_result[0]['db_username'],
'password' => $d_result[0]['db_pass'],
'database' => $d_result[0]['db_name'],
'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
'dbprefix' => '',
'pconnect' => TRUE,
'db_debug' => TRUE,
'cache_on' => FALSE,
'cachedir' => '',
'char_set' => 'utf8',
'dbcollat' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
'swap_pre' => '',
'encrypt' => FALSE,
'compress' => FALSE,
'stricton' => FALSE,
'failover' => array(),
'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

I do collect `$d_result[0]['db_username'], $d_result[0]['db_pass']` etc from client database. You may take it from session or whatever. hope it helps.